# Overwriting excel file data in SSIS

Tags: sql, excel, ssis

I want to overwrite all data in an excel sheet using SSIS. I followed this guide https://dwhanalytics.wordpress.com/2011/04/07/ssis-dynamically-generate-excel-tablesheet/. When I run my package I get the following error:

> Description: Executing the query "CREATE TABLE `Excel Destination` (      `clientNr` ..." failed with the following error: "Table 'Excel Destination' already exists."

The problem lies with the "Drop Excel Table" Execute SQL Task. The "DROP TABLE `Excel Destination`" query does not delete the Excel Destination sheet in my case - it just deletes the headers, therefore a new sheet with the exact same name cannot be created. How can I delete the sheet instead of deleting the headers?

Answer (score 2):

You would have to do that through C# / VB.NET script task. SQL task will not let you do what you wanted to do. [Here](http://www.xtremedotnettalk.com/interoperation-office-integration/74551-rename-excel-sheet-using-asp-net.html) is how you can do that, but basically you will need to get a worksheet by index (hopefully you have that), change the name and then save it. Pretty straight forward in Script task:

```
object m = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
Excel.ApplicationClass app = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
Excel.Workbook xls = (Workbook)app.Workbooks.Open(path, m,m,m,m,m,m,m,m,m,m,m,m,m,m);
Excel.Worksheet sheet = (Worksheet)xls.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
sheet.Name = "myName";
xls.Save();
app.Application.Workbooks.Close();
```

Comment: In the end I decided to create a new excel file each time the SSIS package is initiated and then delete it afterwards. It acomplishes the same result without the need for scripting. Thanks for the contribution - I'm sure your script will help someone in the future.